# how to get TabHeader on trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

i have a tabcontrol.  i'm trying to pass the tabcontrol as a parameter to figure out the selected tab item so i can get the tab header name.  Binding this doesn't seem to work.  ideas?

```
<TabControl Background="#FFF9F9F9" Height="650">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger  EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <n:ExecuteCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateTabCommand}" Parameter="{Binding this}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

in my viewmodel constructor i have:

```
_updateTabCommand = new ActionCommand< TabControl>(UpdateTab);
```

private method:

```
public void UpdateTab(TabControl tabControl)
{
    var tabItem = (TabItem)tabControl.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use `ElementName` binding.

### Example:

```
<TabControl Background="#FFF9F9F9"
            Height="650"
            Name="TabControl1">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger  EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateTabCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TabControl1}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TabControl>
```

2) Use `FindAncestor` binding:

### Example:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger  EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateTabCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabControl}}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no such thing as `{Binding this}` in WPF. If you want to refer to the element on which you are setting Binding use [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx) binding with mode set to [Self](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.self.aspx).

Second observation. Passing UI elements to ViewModel smells badly (impacts testability, increases code coupling and most likely the class will end up violating more [good design principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29)). The fix is really simple: just bind `TabControl.SelectedItem` to the field on ViewModel.